# Android Converting objects to XML and vice versa

Tags: android, xml, xsd, castor

I created a xsd and I created Java objects using Castor. Then I imported this in my Android project and tried to build an XML from the object, using the marshal method.

```
Marshaller.marshal(v, writer);
```

I received some wired exception trouble processing "`javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.class`":...

So my question is Can I use Castor inside Android, If yes how can I work around this.

If no, what is the neat solution available to convert object to xml and xml to object in Android, similar to Castor.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Note: I didnt get any compile error. But I received the exception when I tried to launch the Android app.

Comment: I ended up using Simple xml from http://simple.sourceforge.net/home.php. This looks light suitable for Android. But this will not create Java objects for your xsd.  You have to create them on your own. Is there a way to build these objects directly from xsd compantible with Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally do not have any experience with Castor but from the website it would seem that it has [dependencies](http://www.castor.org/dependencies.html) which android does not support and therefore cannot be used inside android.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using Simple xml from simple.sourceforge.net/home.php. This looks light suitable for Android. But this will not create Java objects for your xsd. You have to create them on your own. Is there a way to build these objects directly from xsd compantible with Android?